# Discord.py авто обновление ролей спустя время

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Хочу **попробовать** реализовать авто обновление ролей у участников через определенный срок после захода на сервер.
Я хотел спросить как это можно реализовать? (что для этого понадобится и т.д)
**Главный вопрос** нужно ли мне делать файл в котором будут хранится данные пользователя такие как: дата входа и роль которая есть у него сейчас или это можно вытянуть с самого сервера через код?

Answer (score 0):

При выходе с сервера записывайте в бд member.id и member.roles, а при входе перебираете роли через цикл for, выдавая их.